# How to execute a git project with different input data?

Tags: r, sql

I would like to run [this](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD) project and receive result from this project

However I have problem to execute the step

> mailcorpus.json created by executing the sql script
>   data/get_mail_corpus.sql on the Apache database

because this is the sql query

> https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD/blob/master/data/get_mail_corpus.sql

```
SET group_concat_max_len=18446744073709547520;

SELECT 

CONCAT(

'[',

GROUP_CONCAT(

JSON_OBJECT(

'id',messages.message_id,

'mailing_list_url',messages.mailing_list_url,

'type_of_recipient',messages_people.type_of_recipient,

'email_address',messages_people.email_address,

'message_body',messages.message_body,

'is_response_of',messages.is_response_of

) SEPARATOR ',\r'),

']') AS list

FROM messages

LEFT JOIN messages_people

ON messages.message_id = messages_people.message_id

AND messages.mailing_list_url = messages_people.mailing_list_url

WHERE email_address IN ('dr@gorsvet.kz', 'mathews@uk2.net', 'd.jentsch@fu-berlin.de', 'atul.soman@microfocus.com', 'kkrugler_lists@transpac.com', 'hcorg@minions.org.pl', 'bruno.ronchetti@mac.com', 'christophe.thiebaud@sap.com', 'kc.baltz@copart.com', 'havanki4j@gmail.com', 'joseph.obernberger@ngc.com', 'goran@roseen.se', 'hboutemy@apache.org', 'johann@gyger.name', 'fredrik@jonson.org', 'jose-marcio.martins@mines-paristech.fr', 'dmytro.kostiuchenko@gmail.com', 'jochen.wiedmann@softwareag.com', 'guyskk@qq.com', 'alejandroscandroli@gmail.com', '1983-01-06@gmx.net', 'jstrayer@proofpoint.com', 'daniel@degu.cl', 'hontvari@flyordie.com', 'david@andl.org', 'gholmes@pinsightmedia.com', 'dennis.geurts@luminis.eu', 'carlspring@gmail.com', 'jozef.koval@protonmail.ch', 'gabriele.ctn@gmail.com', 'ashish.disawal@evivehealth.com', 'aarslan2@anadolu.edu.tr', 'kshukla@yahoo-inc.com', 'alex.huang@gmail.com', 'markus@openindex.io', 'marohn@sipgate.de', 'ea@apache.org', 'krzysztof.szalast@gmail.com', 'kfoskey@tpg.com.au', 'krauss@in.tum.de', 'kenhans@hotmail.co.uk', 'jokin.c@odeian.com', 'eitch@eitchnet.ch', 'm.kristian@web.de', 'bob.sandiford@sirsidynix.com', 'asandstrom2@eastlink.ca', 'kelly@apache.org', 'antony.blakey@linkuistics.com.au', 'ashawki@hotmail.com', 'h.klocker-mark@tsn.at');
```

but the database is not available to make the query. How is it possible to use my own input and take the rinal results?

Comment: Apparently the most direct way would be to convert your data to JSON format and give this as input instead of mailcorpus.json

Comment: @Erwan but how can I convert it as the don't make available the json format that is needed i.e. id, text etc

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I wrote an answer in case it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the program expects a JSON file (probably) like this:

```
[
    {
    "id": ".......",
    "mailing_list_url": "......",
    "type_of_recipient": "......",
    "email_address": ".......",
    "message_body": "......",
    "is_response_of": "......"
    },
    {
    "id": ".......",
    "mailing_list_url": "......",
    "type_of_recipient": "......",
    "email_address": ".......",
    "message_body": "......",
    "is_response_of": "......"
    },

    ...

    {
    "id": ".......",
    "mailing_list_url": "......",
    "type_of_recipient": "......",
    "email_address": ".......",
    "message_body": "......",
    "is_response_of": "......"
    }
]
```

So if your data can be somehow converted to this that would be ideal, I guess. Otherwise you might have to play with the code.

Alternatively you could contact the authors by opening an issue.